# Routing Rest call across all pods in openshift

Tags: openshift, rest

Hi I have rest url configured in my application and I have deployed the application in openshift with 2 pods running. Everytime hitting thele url only one pod recieves the call and other doesn't. Any configuration need to be added in openshift Please let me know your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The object you are looking for is called a `Service` ([documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html#services)):

> A Kubernetes service serves as an internal load balancer. It identifies a set of replicated pods in order to proxy the connections it receives to them. Backing pods can be added to or removed from a service arbitrarily while the service remains consistently available, enabling anything that depends on the service to refer to it at a consistent address. The default service clusterIP addresses are from the OpenShift Container Platform internal network and they are used to permit pods to access each other.

So in OpenShift, you typically have the following setup with a `Route`, a `Service` and multiple Pods:

```
                                             +-----+
                                       +---->+ Pod |
                                       |     +-----+
        +-------+         +---------+  |
+------>+ Route +-------->+ Service +--+
        +-------+         +---------+  |
                                       |     +-----+
                                       +---->+ Pod |
                                             +-----+
```

If you already have a `Service` defined, you'll need to check the `spec.selector` for which Pods are actually selected by the `Service` and where the `Service` forwards the request to.

Also, `Routes` allow [Sticky Sessions](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#routes-sticky-sessions), so maybe sticky sessions are enabled for your `Route`, you may need to check that.